# Installing Ubuntu in a Windows Laptop in Dual Boot mode-Please help

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a Hp Pavillion Laptop with Windows  8.1  SL installed .I want to install Ubuntu in my Laptop with dual boot. I have downloaded the Latest Ubuntu iso.

Please help in getting the step to install ubuntu in windows 8.1 as dual boot.

The Configurations are
Processor: Intel Core i3 3rd Gen
HDD: 500GB-(Partitions-C,D,E,F; C Drive contains Windows ,D and E are Free and F is the rocovery drive.)
RAm:4 GB
Graphics:2GB

Comment: First try to burn the iso to a DVD or pendrive and start your installation. If you get ant error, we are here to help. Posting the whole process might be a little tiring for most of us. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 will be installed with UEFI Mode. To boot from linux, you need to change it to legacy mode in BIOS.

To get BIOS Settings:

Windows+c -> Click on settings -> Change PC Settings -> General -> Advanced Startup -> Restart Now -> Troubleshoot -> UEFI Firmware settings -> Restart

If u want to boot to windows u need to boot from UEFI mode, boot from legacy mode for linux.

Hope it helps.